# nodejs async function how to?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

So I am not sure how to convert a function that I have that is built synchronously but uses asynchronous calls.

```
do_thing = () => {
  var N = new Thing(); //sync

  N.do_that();        // calls fs.readFile() and does some stuff with data  :async
  this.array.push(N); // sync but does not affect anything
  this.save();        // calls fs.writeFile() but needs info from N that is not created yet as N.do_that() is not done
}
```

I am not sure how to make it so when `N.do_that()` is done it then calls `this.save()`. I do not want to use `fs.readFileSync()` or `fs.writeFileSync()`. I would like to know how to something like:

```
N.do_that().then( this.save() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Inside my N.do_that(); I added a callback, something like so:

```
do_that = (callback) => {
  fs.readFile("file", (err, fd) => {
    // do stuff with fd

    callback();
    return;

  });
}
```

then rather than calling :

```
N.do_that();
array.push(N);
this.save();
```

I did

```
N.do_that(() => {
  array.push(N);
  this.save();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 3rd-party, open source tool that already gives you Promisified versions to help! One Google search revealed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-promise

Otherwise, you can promisify the method yourself using tips from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34642827/3814251.

(Alternatively, use callbacks, which you've posted in your own answer.)