# Observables in nestjs - Reading a file asynchronously

Tags: node.js, rxjs, observable, nestjs, behaviorsubject

I am trying a use case of reading a json file asynchronously and sending it out as a response (as a rxjs observable data). Here is the service that I use

```
 import { logger } from './../../shared/utils/logger';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, pipe, of, from, throwError, merge} from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, scan, take, debounce, switchMap, retry, catchError, mergeMap, delay, zip, tap, mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpResponseModel } from '../model/config.model';
import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';
@Injectable()
export class NewProviderService {
    serviceSubject: BehaviorSubject<HttpResponseModel[]>;
    filePath: string;
    httpResponseObjectArray: HttpResponseModel[];
    constructor() {
        this.serviceSubject = new BehaviorSubject<HttpResponseModel[]>([]);
        this.filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './../../shared/assets/httpTest.json');
        this.setSubject();
    }


 readFileFromJSON() {
      this.readFileFromJsonSync();
      fs.exists(this.filePath.toString(), exists => {
        if (exists) {
           fs.readFile(this.filePath.toString(), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
                logger.info('file read without parsin', data);
                this.httpResponseObjectArray = JSON.parse(data).HttpTestResponse;
                logger.info('array obj is:', this.httpResponseObjectArray);
                logger.info('file read after parsing', JSON.parse(data));
                return this.httpResponseObjectArray;
            });
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    });
}


getObservable(): Observable<HttpResponseModel[]> {
       // create an observable
        // return Observable.create(observer => {
        //     observer.next(this.readFileFromJSON());
        // });

        return of(this.readFileFromJsonSync()).pipe(map(data => {
            logger.info('inside obs methid', data);
            return data;
        }));

    }

    setSubject() {
        this.getObservable().subscribe(data => {
            logger.info('data before setting in sub', data);
            this.serviceSubject.next(data);
        });
    }
}
```

So I wanted to subscribe to this emitted observable in the controller, but the values are getting read after I have subscribed and read the subject (`BehaviorSubject`). I understand that I am kind of doing something wrong with the subscription and emitting of data, but couldn't understand where I am doing wrong. Every time the controller prints **'data subscribed undefined'** and then continues to read the file and emit the observable

This is the controller data

```
@Get('/getJsonData')
  public async getJsonData(@Req() requestAnimationFrame, @Res() res) {
    this.newService.serviceSubject.subscribe(data => {
      logger.info('data subscribed', data);
      res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(data);
    });

  }
```

It works well if I read the file synchronously

replace `readFileFromJSON()` with the following method and it works well

```
readFileFromJsonSync(): HttpResponseModel[] {
        const objRead = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(this.filePath.toString(), {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
        logger.info('object read is', objRead.HttpTestResponse);
        return objRead.HttpTestResponse;

    }
```

So I am missing something while reading the file async. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't actually return anything in `readFileFromJSON`. It will asynchronously run `fs.exists` and `fs.readFile` and the corresponding callbacks but the result from the callbacks is ignored.

You should use `Promises` instead. You can either create a `Promise` yourself or use a library like bluebird that transforms `fs` from a callback based API to a `Promise` based API. For more information see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34642827/4694994).

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(this.filePath.toString(), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err); 
        } else {
            const httpResponseObjectArray = JSON.parse(data).HttpTestResponse;
            resolve(httpResponseObjectArray);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I created a promise API just like above and converted the observable method to read from the promise using "from" operator. It worked !!!.