# How to change a promise with async await function to observable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, es6-promise, nestjs

I have a Nestjs rest server with a controller and a service.

In my controller, there is the get function, when someone makes a get request:

```
@Get()
getAllFoos() {
    return this.fooService.getAllFoos();
}
```

In my service, there is this function to get the documents from a database

```
 async getAllFoos(): Promise<foos[]> {
    try {
        return await this.fooModel.find().exec();
    } catch(e) {
        return e;
    }
```

This works!
I now need to change this to make it work with observables.
I changed the controller to:

```
@Get()
getAllFoos() {
    this.fooService.getAllFoos().subscribe(
        response => {
            console.log(response);

        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
            console.log('completed');

    });
}
```

And the service to this:

```
    getAllFoos(): Observable<foos[]> {
        try {
            this.fooModel.find().exec();
        } catch(e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
```

The error I get is

```
[Nest] 7120   - 2019-2-20 15:29:51   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined +4126ms
```

The error comes from

```
this.fooService.getAllFoos().subscribe(
```

this line from the controller. I really have no clue, what to change to make it work now.

Any help or idea is appreciated!

Comment: In the service inside try{} don’t you need a return statement similar to your catch{}..

Comment: I tried that. My IDE is marking the line red then with this message: "Type 'Promise<foos[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<foos[]>': _isScalar, soure, operator, lift and 6 more.

Comment: I dont know why it expects a promise still?!

Comment: What about not using observable as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770820/10634638

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Promise can not be cast as Observable. Create an observable with `Observable.from()` method ([docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from)).

```js
getAllFoos(): Observable<foos[]> {
    return Observable.from(this.fooModel.find().exec());
}
```

**rxjs versions < 6:**

```js
getAllFoos(): Observable<foos[]> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.fooModel.find().exec());
}
```