# JavaScript: Undefined type when attempting to return a string after reading a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am new to JavaScript & writing JS code in Node.JS v12.13.1.

I'm attempting to read a file asynchronously and return the string value by means of promises.

Thus far most of the functions return a value of undefined, while others return a value of [object Promise].

The writeFile function works, and I can verify the out.txt contains "Test Data"

I have conducted research on stack overflow posts, and i'm just confused.
[How to read file with async/await properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867517/how-to-read-file-with-async-await-properly)
[Using filesystem in node.js with async / await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593875/using-filesystem-in-node-js-with-async-await)
[Using Promises with fs.readFile in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628305/using-promises-with-fs-readfile-in-a-loop)

API Documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Could somebody please enlighten me on what I'm missing? It would be greatly appreciated as I have been researching with trial and error for about 3 full days now.

Thanks!

```
function writeFile(data) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile('out.txt', data, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}

function readFile1() {
    const fs = require('fs').promises;
    (async() =>  {
    try {
      const result = await fs.readFileSync('out.txt', 'utf8');
      console.log(result);
   } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
   }
    })();
}

function readFile2() {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const { promisify } = require('util');
    const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

    (async() =>  {
    try {
        const result = await readFile('out.txt', 'utf8');
        console.log(result);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    })();
}

function readFile3() {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const util = require('util');
    const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

    function getStuff() {
        return readFile('out.txt', 'utf8');
    }
    getStuff().then(data => {
        console.log("Inside getStuff Method: "+data);
    })
}

function readFile4() {
    const fs = require('fs');    
    const fsPromises = fs.promises;
  try {  
    return fsPromises.readFile('out.txt');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error occured while reading file!', err);
  }
}

async function readFile5() {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const fsPromises = fs.promises;
    let fileHandle = null;
    try {
        fileHandle = await fsPromises.open('out.txt');
        await fileHandle.readFile();
    } finally {
        if (fileHandle) {
            await fileHandle.close();
        }
    }
    return fs.readFileSync('out.txt', 'utf8');
}

writeFile("Test Data");
myString = readFile5();
console.log("The String Value is: " + myString);
```

Comment: `readFile5` is async ... therefore, when doing `myString = readFile5();` - it is guaranteed that `myString` will be a Promise, regardless of what you do (right or wrong) inside that function, it returns a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay that makes sense that it returns the promise, and it is showing in my console as: "The String Value is: [object Promise]" --- but where i'm confused is how to get the actual text "Test Data" to display instead of [object Promise], maybe i'm missing a step?

Comment: promises have a `.then` method ... or use async/await

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you very much, I remember going through this on an AngularJS coarse by Rahul Shetty up on udemy, he explains the then() method for promises too. I appreciate ya taking the time to help me out with this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open the file in read mode

```
fileHandle = await fsPromises.open('out.txt','r');
```

then.

you can do like below

```
 async function getPromiseResolved() {
    writeFile("Test Data");
    myString =  await readFile5();
    console.log("The String Value is: " + myString);
    }

getPromiseResolved()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516570/6302996

full code

```js
// This is your Editor pane. Write your JavaScript here and 
// use the command line to execute commands

function writeFile(data) {
  const fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile('out.txt', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}

async function readFile5() {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const fsPromises = fs.promises;
  let fileHandle = null;
  try {
    fileHandle = await fsPromises.open('out.txt', 'r');
    await fileHandle.readFile();
  } finally {
    if (fileHandle) {
      await fileHandle.close();
    }
  }
  var myString = await fs.readFileSync('out.txt', 'utf8');
  return myString;
}
async function getPromiseResolved() {
  writeFile("Test Data");
  myString = await readFile5();

  console.log("The String Value is: " + myString);
}

getPromiseResolved()
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you very much for your help on this! =) I think this will be extremely valuable for other people sharing the same struggles.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const readFile = filepath =>
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
      fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', 
         (err, result) => err ? reject(err): resolve(result)))
```

This is basically what `promisify` does to the method. This is how you can convert any callback-style function to return a Promise.

Comment: Thank you for sharing bro, I'll add this to my arsenal of knowledge ;)