# Get the array value of a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sendgrid, new-operator

I'm trying to send multiple attachments with Sendgrid with a new promise as below. I want to return an array of objects but I don't understand how to do so. `emailAttachments` contains my 3 objects, but how can I return the array? Can you tell me what's wrong in my code?

```
const emailAttachments = []

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    pdfList.map(item => {

        fs.readFile((item.frDoc), (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              return { handled: false }
            }

            if (data) {
                
                emailAttachments.push({
                    content: data.toString('base64'),
                    filename: `document.pdf`,
                    type: 'application/pdf',
                    disposition: 'attachment'
                })

            }
        });
    })

    resolve(emailAttachments)
})
```

Comment: `map` returns a new array so there's no need to `push` elements into an empty array. [This may also give you some clues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628305/using-promises-with-fs-readfile-in-a-loop) as to using `readFile` with promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```js
async function getEmailAttachments(pdfList) {
    const emailAttachments = await Promise.all(pdfList.map((item) => {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            fs.readFile((item.frDoc), (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject({ handled: false });
                }
                if (data) {
                    resolve({
                        content: data.toString('base64'),
                        filename: `document.pdf`,
                        type: 'application/pdf',
                        disposition: 'attachment'
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }));
    return emailAttachments;
}
```

[EDIT] Or using the promise version of readFile (sugestion of @derpirscher):

```js
async function getEmailAttachments(pdfList) {
    const emailAttachments = await Promise.all(pdfList.map(async (item) => {
        const data = await fs.promises.readFile(item.frDoc);
        return {
            content: data.toString('base64'),
            filename: `document.pdf`,
            type: 'application/pdf',
            disposition: 'attachment'
        };
    }));
    return emailAttachments;
}
```

Comment: Why wrapping the callback based `readFile` if there is a promise based version already included in the node api?

Comment: Good ideia, that would simplify the code!

Comment: Now you will get a syntax error, because `await` can only be used inside of an `async` function (and `item => { ...}` is not async)

Comment: I implemented the second solution and it's working, thank you both !

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing callback functions and promises. That won't work. I'd suggest to use the promise API of the `fs` module supported since node 10.

Furthermore, you need to await the filereading before resolving promise, which you currently don't do.

```
import { promises as fsp} from "fs"; //use the Promise API from fs

async function getAttachments(pdffiles) {
  return Promise.all(pdffiles.map(pdf => fsp.readFile(pdf.frDoc)))
    .then(files => files.map(f => ({
       content: f.toString("base64"),
       filename: "document.pdf",
       type: "application/pdf",
       disposition: "attachment"
     })));

}
```